# Copy Categories for Reply/Reply All and Forward

Tags: vba, outlook, categories

The common solution on the net is to make a registry edit for all Categories to be transferred from the incoming message to the Reply/Reply all and forward messages.

My office will not allow a registry change.

How can I accomplish the task to COPY and PASTE all of my assigned categories?

Answer (score 0):

It is not usual to categorize outgoing mail. I believe most (maybe all) will find categories are removed upon sending.

```
Private Sub Categories_reply()

Dim currItem As mailItem
Dim repItem As mailItem

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

Set repItem = currItem.reply
repItem.Categories = currItem.Categories
repItem.Display

repItem.Save

If repItem.Categories <> "" Then

    MsgBox " Viewed in Drafts folder, with a categories column, you should see: " & _
        vbCr & repItem.Categories & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "The categories will likely be removed upon sending."

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niton,  I can not thank you enough for the code.  It works perfectly!!